# Amazon: TopSeller return more than top 10

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

How can we retrieve more than top 10 best seller using [Amazon's Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html).

By digging into their API, I found 2 operations that might needed:

First is [BrowseNodeLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeLookup.html), this can successfully retrieve the top 10 best seller but there is no ItemPage parameter.

Second is [ItemSearch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html), this seems have &ItemPage=2 parameter, &ResponseGroup=SalesRank and &Sort=salesrank. But the sort is not working. Below is sample request:

```
> http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService
> &Operation=ItemSearch 
> &SubscriptionId=<subscription_id>
> &AssociateTag=<associate_tag> 
> &Version=2011-08-01
> &SearchIndex=Electronics 
> &BrowseNode=2407747011
> &ItemPage=2
> &ResponseGroup=SalesRank 
> &Sort=salesrank
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

With Amazon's policy, unfortunately you cannot get more than 10 items per queue.

Comment: Is there a way to navigate to next page? &ItemPage=2 is not working

Answer (score 0):

"The maximum ItemPage number that can be returned is 10"
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

So if there are enough results, you can get up to 100 items.

I think that "salesrank" sort parameter is working, but not as expected. Because if you don't include this parameters, results won't be ordered at all.